# Get posts,comments,users in one query Neo4j C# MVC5

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I have the following classes

Post.cs

```cs
public class Post: Neo4jEntity
    {
        public Post()
        {
            Label = "Post";
            ID = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreation { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment.cs

```cs
    public class Comment:Neo4jEntity
        {
            public Comment()
            {
                Label = "Comment";
                ID = new Guid();
            }
            public Guid ID { get; set; }
            public string Content{ get; set; }
            public DateTime CreationDate{ get; set; }

        }
```

ApplicationUser.cs

```
public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
        {
            public ApplicationUser()
            {
                Label = "ApplicationUser";
            }
            public string FirstName{ get; set; }
            public string SecondName{ get; set; }
            public Sex Sex{ get; set; }//enum


        }
```

I want to fetch from Database All Posts which have Comments which added ApplicationUser.

```
 var posts = _graphClient.Cypher
                    .Match("(user:ApplicationUser)-[:POST]-> (posts)-[:HAS]->comments<-[:ADD]-(users)")
                    .Return(()=>Return.As<Post>("posts","comments","users"))
                    .Limit(50)
                    .Results.ToList();
```

I want to create a Model from this query then pass this Model to View to make something like this:

```
foreach(var post in Model.Posts)
{
  <div>@post.DateCreation</div>
  <div>@post.Author.FirstName</div>
  <div>@post.Content</div>
  foreach(var comment in post.Comments)
  {
      <div>@comment.Author.Name</div>
      <div>@comment.Content</div>
  }

}
```

I don't know how to return a Model from cypher query which will be fit to foreach above. I have to do a ViewModel which have Post, List of Comments? How to include the User who add a comment?
How should query look like in C#?

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific I'm afraid - what doesn't work? Do you get an error? What are you expecting back? Can you try the `Cypher` in the Neo4j admin page and get that working first. One thing that is obviously a bit squif is the `Return(()=>Return.As<Post>()` first it's missing a closing `)` and second - you would need to put `Return.As<Post>("SOMETHING HERE")` otherwise Neo4j has *no* idea what to return

Comment: Hullo, I see you've made some updates - I've only just noticed - sorry - feel free to comment to let me know. In your example View code - you access an `Author` property on both your `Post` and `Comment` class - but neither has this - is this the `user` / `users` fields you're trying to return?

Comment: In Post Author is a single User who added post. In Comment is a single User too who added comment to post. Yes I'am trying to return this users from query too.